# Why we use Git Keys

Tags: git

I am new to git. Why we use keys in Git? Public and private keys to configure git repositories? Can we configure git without keys?
How to use public keys generated and what is the need of this?

Answer (score 3):

SSH is used as an authentication and communication mechanism between machines and the git server. Depending on what you are using, there may be other means of authentication/communication protocols available.

GitHub for instance offers HTTPS and SSH. Have a look [HERE](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

The intermediary point of SSH authentication is the user's machine. As Miky Dinescu pointed out, the public/private key pair is the authentication/validation mechanism.

I see no reason why you would have to push and pull from one repository to the other. That's not the way it works. For team work purposes, you have forks, pull requests, merge functionality and a bunch of other stuff.

Think about the logistics of your project and figure out how many repositories are required. If the client and server are completely separated with entirely different files/structure and perhaps different teams working on each of them, more repositories are very practical.

If it's just you trying to grasp version control and working on a small project, you don't really need two repos. Give me some more details about your current scenario and will be more helpful.

Comment: But if I am using my two own repositories to pull and push from and to to other one the would I have to use key mechanism??

Comment: I am using client git repository and connected to central repository on the server. A server guy has been setup my public key with central repo. So I want to know what exactly he did on the server? I know what I did on my side to connect to server repo.

Answer (score 2):

We use public/private keys because they are the crux of asymmetric cryptography which makes it possible to authenticate and authorize users to access a repository.

The use of public keys is important in generating digital message signatures which authenticate and guarantee the integrity of committing changes into the repository.

On the other hand they also provide a natural way to confirm the authenticity and integrity of the files in the repository itself when checking out code.

And since Git is designed to be a distributed source control repository system it needs to be able to allow many people access to download and upload data without an always on connection but at the same time without sacrificing security.